# Jest: Mocking constructor to return error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm having trouble trying to mock a class constructor in jest.

I have some code similar to this where I want to have code coverage for the catch

```
   try {
    redis = new Redis(params); 
   }catch(err){
    return reject(new Error());
   }
```

The mock I'm trying to create in a unit test so that "new Redis" throws an error includes something like this:

```
jest.mock('ioredis', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      constructor: () => {
        throw new Error();
      },
    };
   });
 });
```

The documentation doesn't seem to have a good example for mocking constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) explains how classes are mocked. It doesn't show `constructor` method because it's irrelevant in these scenarios. In JavaScript, `constructor` is a special method that is normally equal to constructor function itself, `Class === Class.prototype.constructor`. `constructor` is used in inheritance but normally isn't called directly, so mocking or even mentioning it in this scenario doesn't make sense. It's constructor function that is called and it should be mocked instead:

```
jest.mock('ioredis', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    throw new Error();
  });
});
```